# When wiring a 175amp 3Pole breaker

Tags: electrical

How do I know which is the load side when hooking up a 3 pole 175amp Ac breaker? Both sides look the same and no markings. And what would happen if it was hooked up wrong. Thanks

Comment: More details are really needed here.  How about a photo and make/model of the breaker in question?

Comment: electrically they are equivalent  unless shared with a bus on one side

Answer (score 0):

### If it doesn't have markings, then it doesn't matter

As per UL489 and other applicable standards, a breaker that lacks LINE/LOAD markings is tested to be hooked up either way around without issue.

Answer (score -1):

If there are no markings or evidence of a shared bus , then each side is isolated.

I would think if the normally ON direction of the switch could point towards the Input terminals, that would be logical to me.

- then up is away from the breaker panel towards the input Feed.
- if it is sideways does it matter?

e.g.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I new to the posting stuff any suggestions on how I post a picture. I copied the pic but won’t let me post

Comment: The breaker will be mounted in a sealed case for portable distribution systems.

Comment: It’s a 175amp ABB 3 pole breaker Ac